# Should I use redux dispatch during initial rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to build a E-Commerce Store and it requires that I initially load a list of trending products on the home page.

Here, I can simply do without redux and simply display the data (roughly) of this sort

```
const trendingProducts = await get('/api/trendingProducts')
render(){
  <TrendingProducts data={this.trendingProducts.data} />
}
```

I am using redux in my application. So should I do a dispatch elsewhere to fetch the trending products ?

All in all, Should I always handle every single fetch / render using only Redux dispatch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is a store management for your application's state. Redux's `dispatch` is used to dispatching actions that aims to update your application's state in some way.

Hence if your application logic requires displaying information that belongs to your application's state - you need to take it from Redux store. If such information is not yet available into Redux store - you need to obtain it from some source (e.g. `fetch`) and use `dispatch` to update your application's state. If information, you're trying to display is not part of your application's state - you can display it directly, but in this case you'll need to handle React lifecycle events by yourself too since React re-draws components upon component's state change.

UPDATE: Your example code will work fine if you'll put your `trendingProducts` into component's state:

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            trendingProducts: {}
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('/api/trendingProducts').then(data => this.setState({trendingProducts: data}));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TrendingProducts data={this.state.trendingProducts}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If I start using Dispatch and Store for all fetch / render / action events, Wouldn't the Store get very huge ?

Comment: It really depends on what data do you have for your application, there is no general answer. Redux simply allows you to manage your application state and management involves data removal too. So it is really up to you

Answer (score 0):

That is very subjective and there is no correct answer but I can tell you by my experience.

**Always keep your business logic separate from your component**

If you're making API calls then you should definitely dispatch an action rather writing this in your component because there are lot of **redux-like** stores are emerging and it might happen that later you want to change your store using some different architecture. Your *view* layer should be independent on your API calls (business logic). In this way, while refactoring your app again, you'll just have to change the logic and your view will remain the same.

I'm writing this on my experience where we started refactoring the whole app from `backbone` to `React`. We had `models` and `collections`, we changed the whole `html` but we didn't change any business logic initially, just the `views` were deprecated but later we removed the business logic too using redux (iteratively). You should write your code in such a way that it has maximum `reusability` after all that's what `React` is and that's how you should write your front-end code.

Also, the component's state can reside in component where the whole app doesn't get affected. e.g. showing or hiding of a third-pane or overlay etc.